# Table position over div with function

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, position

I want to program a shopping list. My problem with that is: I have created several div with images that have a function. They insert the content into a table. But if I put the table to the left of the div, my function does not work anymore. Can you help me? I have already tried the z-index. Unfortunately no success.

```
<body style="background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(77,121,9,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);">
      <!--Überschrift-->
        <center><h1 style="font-family: Magneto">Einkaufsliste</h1></center>



        <!--Div mit Funktion-->
        <div style=" background-image: url('Apfel.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px" onclick="check('Obst')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Wurst.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Aufschnitt/Wurst')"></div>
        <div style=" background-image: url('Gemüse.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px; margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Gemüse')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Käse.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Käse')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Soft.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px; margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Softdrink')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Wasser.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Wasser')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Bier.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px; margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Bier')" ></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Süßigkeiten.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('SÜßigkeiten')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Butter.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px;  margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Butter')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Milch.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Milch')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Mehl.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px;  margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Mehl')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Eier.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Eier')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Brot.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px;  margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Brot/Brötchen')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Nudel.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px;margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Nudeln')" ></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Fleisch.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px;  margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Fleisch')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Öl.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px;margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Öl')" ></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('Essig.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px; margin-left: 1400px;  margin-top: 50px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Essig')"></div>
        <div style="background-image: url('joghurt.jpg'); border: 4px solid black; width: 100px; padding-top: 100px; background-size: 100px 100px;margin-left: 1200px; margin-top: -107px; z-index: 1" onclick="check('Joghurt')" ></div>

        <!--Tabele-->

        <form style=" z-index: -1; margin-top: -1350px">
            <table style=" border: 1px solid white;">
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l1"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l2"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l3"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l4"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l5"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l6"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l7"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l8"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l9"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l10"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l11"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l12"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l13"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l14"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l15"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l16"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l17"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l18"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l19"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l20"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l21"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l22"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l23"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l24"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
                 <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="l25"></td>
                <td><input type="number"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr><!--Reset button-->
                    <td><button type="reset">Liste Löschen</button></td>
                    <!--Vermerk-->
                    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Vermerk"></td>
                </tr>

            </table><br>            
        </form>
```

```
 //###################################################################################
            /*
            Funktion in der Geprüft wird ob der Platz schon belegt ist, und wenn, wird in eine 
            andere Tabellen Zeile Geschrieben
            */
            //####################################################################################
            function check(x) {
                var l1 = document.getElementById('l1').value
                var l2 = document.getElementById('l2').value
                var l3 = document.getElementById('l3').value
                var l4 = document.getElementById('l4').value
                var l5 = document.getElementById('l5').value
                var l6 = document.getElementById('l6').value
                var l7 = document.getElementById('l7').value
                var l8 = document.getElementById('l8').value
                var l9 = document.getElementById('l9').value
                var l10 = document.getElementById('l10').value
                var l11 = document.getElementById('l11').value
                var l12 = document.getElementById('l12').value
                var l13 = document.getElementById('l13').value
                var l14 = document.getElementById('l14').value
                var l15 = document.getElementById('l15').value
                var l16 = document.getElementById('l16').value
                var l17 = document.getElementById('l17').value
                var l18 = document.getElementById('l18').value
                var l19 = document.getElementById('l19').value
                var l20 = document.getElementById('l20').value
                var l21 = document.getElementById('l21').value
                var l22 = document.getElementById('l22').value
                var l23 = document.getElementById('l23').value
                var l24 = document.getElementById('l24').value
                var l25 = document.getElementById('l25').value

                //##############################################
                //#### Hier wird die value geprüft
                //##############################################

                if (l1 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l1').value = x;
                } else if (l2 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l2').value = x;
                } else if (l3 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l3').value = x;
                } else if (l4 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l4').value = x;
                } else if (l5 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l5').value = x;
                } else if (l6 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l6').value = x;
                } else if (l7 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l7').value = x;
                } else if (l8 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l8').value = x;
                } else if (l9 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l9').value = x;
                } else if (l10 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l10').value = x;
                } else if (l11 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l11').value = x;
                } else if (l12 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l12').value = x;
                } else if (l13 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l13').value = x;
                } else if (l14 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l14').value = x;
                } else if (l15 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l15').value = x;
                } else if (l16 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l16').value = x;
                } else if (l17 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l17').value = x;
                } else if (l18 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l18').value = x;
                } else if (l19 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l19').value = x;
                } else if (l20 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l20').value = x;
                } else if (l21 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l21').value = x;
                } else if (l22 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l22').value = x;
                } else if (l23 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l23').value = x;
                } else if (l24 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l24').value = x;
                } else if (l25 == '') {
                    document.getElementById('l25').value = x;
                }




            }
```

Comment: Give you code and make a picture of what you want to do

Comment: Working example would be great, there is no way to tell what is wrong based on the description.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've added the code below. I want that when I click on a picture, the entry will be placed in the table. In an empty space, of course.

Comment: But the function does not work on the images to the right of the table